# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec(q1) is not working when q1 string variable contains "for" keywork for looping in ffmpeg

Tags: java, ffmpeg, process, runtime

```
String q1 = "for %%i in ('I:\\Test\\M1\\*.*') do D:/Softwares/PC/MultiMedia/Video/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -i '%%' -ab 320k -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 'I:\\Organised\\Audio\\MP3\\M1\\%%~ni.mp3'";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(q1); 
p.waitFor();
System.out.println("Completed");
```

OS: Windows 10

Objective: Converting all FLAC files to mp3 using FFMPEG Libray. Instead of converting one by one using for loop format of ffmpeg to convert all files in a given folder.

Note: Executing in command prompt is working fine. But I can not detect when the conversion is completed. But if I use "Runtime.getRuntime().exec(q1)" I monitor and once it is complete I can do further tasks.

Getting Below error. But same works as a batch file:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "for": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is wrong. What are you trying to do? What OS are you running this on?

Comment: If Unix, then perhaps you need to call `/bin/bash` explicitly

Comment: and if Windows, use `cmd.exe`

Comment: Also, don't ignore the process's output and error streams. Also, use ProcessBuilder and an array of String or a `List<String>`, not Process and one single String.

Comment: Why are you using that `for` at all, when [Java code is perfectly capable of listing a directory’s files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream(java.nio.file.Path))?